# Can any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ be represented as the intersection of closed line segments?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have a question, which is in the title. And the answer in the book is $\mathbf{false}$.

I'm new in topology, but by studying the questions on this site, I understand that for Hausdorff space (which is $\mathbb{R}$) the intersection of an arbitrary number (possibly uncountable) of compact sets is the compact (bounded and closed).

Any closed line segment in $\mathbb{R}$ is a compact. So, if we need to represent a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is a line segment as the intersection of closed line segments we can take this segment and the statement will be true, if the compact set, which we need to represent as an intersection is the point we can use Cantor's intersection theorem according to which the intersection of closed nested line segments, with lengths go to zero, gives one point.

Thus, any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ we can represent as the intersection of closed line segments. Am I wrong, or there is the mistake in the book?

Would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Not all line segments are compact. They should be bounded and contains end points.

Comment: @JohnMa While I understand that a line segment may not contain the end points, can it be unbounded? That's conflicting with the definition of [a line segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment) (at least the one of Wikipedia)

Comment: @JohnMa I've edited the question, closed line segments

Comment: Every OPEN set can be expressed as a countable union of disjoint OPEN intervals. However, the case for closed sets is not so nice as demonstrated by the Cantor Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong, because an intersection of line segments is either empty or a line segment. This would imply the only non-empty compact sets are line segments.

Unfortunately a finite set in $\mathbf R$ is compact, as it is closed and bounded.

Comment: But according to the Cantor's intersection theorem if the lengths of nested closed line segments go to zero there is only one point which is belonged to each line segment. Thus the intersection isn't empty.

Comment: If two points are in the intersection, then then those two points are in every line segment, and hence so are all the points in between.

Comment: @DF: I'm sorry, but $[0,1]\cap[2,3]=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Bernard of course, but what the question? Empty set is a closed and bounded and as you wrote can be represented as the intersection of closed line segments.

Comment: But a set of two points is not, since it's not in interval.

Comment: Because  an intersection of line segments is a  line segment, and a set of two points is not a line segment.

Comment: @Bernard I've understood. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome! In topological terms, the argument is that the `connected` subspaces of $\mathbf R$ are exactly the intervals (not necessarily open nor closed) and  a finite set of $n>1$ points is not connected.